# Disable gzip compression of Keycloak server standalone

Tags: keycloak

Is there a way to disable compression of keycloak server output. I try to rewrite the HTML content so that I can proxy pass the Keycloak front end with my Apache http.

Currently I try ProxyPassReverse, mod_rewrite and mod_substitude but nothing works. IMO the reason is the wildfly server delivere the content gziped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I don't know how. But i would start from here https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/5c98b8c6ae7052b2d906156d8fc212ccd9dfd57d/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/broker/provider/util/SimpleHttp.java. There is `Content-Encoding` parameter, maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can disable this on undertow subsystem in your standalone.xml or standalone-ha.xml (depends on profile you use), by default the undertow has no gzip filtering, but you should see something like this in your config.

```

```
<gzip name="gzipFilter"/>
```

```